# How do you invalidate cache of index.html for a static site hosted on S3 with cloudfront?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

So I have hosted my angular app on s3 with a cloudfront dist. I do file revision-ing (using grunt filerev) to make sure that I never get stale content. But, how should I version the index.html file. Its required because all other files are referenced inside index.html.

I have configured my bucket to be used as a static site. So it just picks up the index.html when I reference the bucket in url.

Cloudfront says that you should set min TTL to 0, so it would always hit origin to serve the content. But, I don't need this since I am doing file revisioning of all my files (except index.html). I can take advantage of cdn caching for these files.

They also say that in order to invalidate a single object, set the max-age headers to 0. I tried adding following to my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0"/>
```

But this does not reflect once you upload on s3. Do I need to explicitly set headers on s3 using s3cmd or dashboard? And do I need to do this every time when index.html changes and I upload it?

I am aware that I could invalidate a single file using cmd but its a repeating process and It would be great if it can take care of itself just by deploying on s3.

Comment: Related: [How to purge CloudFront's cache](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12526/22759).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Although the accepted answer is correct if you are using s3cmd, I was using the AWS CLI, so what I did was the following 2 commands:

First, to actually deploy the code:

`aws s3 sync ./ s3://bucket-name-here/ --delete`

Then, to create an invalidation on CloudFront:

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <distribution-id> --paths /index.html`

Comment: Thanks @Jordan. I am trying this but not getting desired result.

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${CLOUDFRONT_ID} --paths '/index.html'`. any other idea?

Comment: I would check your cloudfront distribution logs to see if the invalidation was triggered, and make sure that the path is correctly displayed there.

Comment: invalidation details from cloudfront distribution shows this alongside other details `objects path /index.html /service-worker.js`. i am deploying react app with service worker enabled

Comment: if i invalidate `--paths /*`, log shows this `object paths /lib /tmp /srv /root /media /opt /mnt /etc /usr /dev /var /sbin /proc /bin /run /sys /home /boot /lib64`

Comment: you should use `--paths "/*"`

Comment: There's no need to invalidate the entire bucket just to invalidate index.html.

Answer (score 10):

I have had the same problem with my static website hosted on S3 and distributed with CloudFront. In my case invalidating `/index.html` didn't work.

I talked with AWS support and what I needed to do was to invalidate with only `/`. This is due I am accessing my website with **https://website.com/** URL and not with **https://website.com/index.html** (which would have brought the updated content with the `/index.html` invalidation). This was done in AWS CloudFront console and not with the AWS CLI.

Comment: Greate. Must be /, not index.html.

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question. I deploy my site to S3 using [`s3cmd` tool](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and there is an option you could provide to invalidate CloudFront cache of all the files changed (diff between your `dist` folder and S3 bucket). This invalidates cache of all the files changed including index file. It usually takes around 15-20 mins to reflect the new changes on production.

Here is the command

```bash
s3cmd sync --acl-public --reduced-redundancy --delete-removed --cf-invalidate [your-distribution-folder]/* s3://[your-s3-bucket]
```

<sup>Note: On macOS, you can install this tool via: `brew install s3cmd`.</sup>

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you have to specify in `[your-distribution-folder]/*`? Is that the same as the **CloudFront Distributions ID**?**Domain Name**? Or **ARN**? These are the fields I see (http://i.imgur.com/8IEEYmS.jpg), but I've tried a bunch and it keeps giving me `ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: 'WHATEVER_I_TRIED' is not an existing file or directory` (on Windows if that matters).

Comment: Also is the `/*` required? Does it signify that everything in the distribution / bucket gets invalidated?

Comment: It should be the name of the bucket/folder you've configured as the root of the website.

Comment: And no. It doesn't invalidate everything. It checks for the difference in files using sync command and only invalidates files that have changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can automate a process using Lambda. It allows you to create a function that will perform certain actions (Object invalidation in your case) in response to certain events (new file in S3).

More information here:
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/

Comment: After manually invalidation of the /index.html I get the previous version of my application. Are you able to get this working?

Comment: Here's a Gist that helped me set this up quickly: https://gist.github.com/supinf/e66fd36f9228a8701706 (I'm not the creator so can't really help if it doesn't work out of the box!)

Answer (score 1):

When you sync local directory with s3, you can do this:

```sh
aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://your-bucket --delete

aws s3 cp \
   s3://your-bucket s3://your-bucket \
   --exclude 'index.html' --exclude 'robots.txt' \ 
   --cache-control 'max-age=604800' \
   --metadata-directive REPLACE --acl public-read \
   --recursive
```

The first command is just a normal sync, the second command enable S3 to return cache-control for all the files except `index.html` and `robots.txt`.

Then your SPA can be fully cached (except `index.html`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `s3cmd sync` and utilize the `--cf-invalidate` option, you may have to also specify `--cf-invalidate-default-index` depending on your setup.

From the man page:

> When using Custom Origin and S3 static website, invalidate the default index file.

This will ensure to also invalidate your index document, most likely index.html, which will otherwise be skipped regardless if updated or not through the sync.